# inverse interpolation of multidimensional grids

Tags: math, 3d, interpolation

I am working on a project of interpolating sample data `{(x_i,y_i)}` where the input domain for `x_i` locates in 4D space and output `y_i` locates in 3D space. I need generate two look up tables for both directions. I managed to generate the `4D -> 3D` table. But the `3D -> 4D` one is tricky. The sample data are not on regular grid points, and it is not one to one mapping. Is there any known method to treat this situation? I did some search online, but what I found is only for `3D -> 3D` mapping, which are not suitable for this case. Thank you!

---

To answer the questions of Spektre:

`X(3D) -> Y(4D)` is the case `1X -> nY`

I want to generate a table that for any given `X`, we can find the value for `Y`. The sample data is not occupy all the domain of `X`. But it's fine, we only need accuracy for point inside the domain of sample data. For example, we have sample data like `{(x1,x2,x3) ->(y1,y2,y3,y4)}`. It is possible we also have a sample data `{(x1,x2,x3) -> (y1_1,y2_1,y3_1,y4_1)}`. But it is OK. We need a table for any `(a,b,c)` in space `X`, it corresponds to ONE `(e,f,g,h)` in space `Y`. There might be more than one choice, but we only need one. (Sorry for the symbol confusing if any)

One possible way to deal with this: Since I have already established a smooth mapping from `Y->X`, I can use Newton's method or any other method to reverse search the point `y` for any given `x`. But it is not accurate enough, and time consuming. Because I need do search for each point in the table, and the error is the sum of the model error with the search error.

So I want to know it is possible to find a mapping directly to interpolate the sample data instead of doing such kind of search in 3.

Answer (score 2):

1. **You are looking for projections/mappings**

   as you mentioned you have projection `X(3D) -> Y(4D)` which is not one to one in your case so what case it is `(1 X -> n Y)` or `(n X -> 1 Y)` or `(n X -> m Y)` ?
2. **you want to use look-up table**

   I assume you just want to generate all `X` for given `Y` the problem with non `(1 to 1)` mappings is that you can use lookup table only if it has

   - all valid points
   - or mapping has some geometric or mathematic symmetry (for example distance between points in `X` and `Y`space is similar,and mapping is continuous)

   You can not interpolate between generic mapped points so the question is what kind of mapping/projection you have in mind?
3. **First the 1->1 projections/mappings interpolation**

   1. **if your `X->Y` projection mapping is suitable for interpolation**

      then for `3D->4D` use **tri-linear** interpolation. Find closest `8` points (each in its axis to form grid hypercube) and interpolate between them in all `4` dimensions
   2. **if your `X<-Y` projection mapping is suitable for interpolation**

      then for `4D->3D` use **quatro-linear** interpolation. Find closest `16` points (each in its axis to form grid hypercube) and interpolate between them in all `3` dimensions.
4. **Now what about `1->n` or `n->m` projections/mappings**

   That solely depends on the projection/mapping properties which I know nothing of. Try to provide an example of your datasets and adding some image would be best.

**[edit1] 1 X <- n Y**

I still would use **quatro-linear** interpolation. You still will need to search your `Y` table but if you group it like `4D` grid then it should be easy enough.

1. **find `16` closest points in `Y`-table to your input `Y` point**

   These points should be the closest points to your `Y` in each `+/-` direction of all axises. In 3D it looks like this:

   [image: tri-linear]

   - red point is your input `Y` point
   - blue points are the found closest points (grid) they do not need to be so symmetric as on image .

   Please do not want me to draw `4D` example that make sense :) (at least for sober mind)
2. **interpolation**

   find corresponding `X` points. If there is more then one per point chose the closer one to the others ... Now you should have `16 X` points and `16+1 Y` points. Then from `Y` points you need just to calculate the distance along lines from your input `Y` point. These distances are used as parameter for linear interpolations. Normalize them to `<0,1>` where

   - 0 means 'left' and 1 means 'right' point
   - 0.5 means exact middle

   You will need this scalar distance in each of `Y`-domain dimension. Now just compute all the `X` points along the linear interpolations until you get the corresponding red point in `X`-domain.

   With **tri-linear** interpolation (`3D`) there are `4+2+1=7` linear interpolations (as on image). For **quatro-linear** interpolation (`4D`) there are `8+4+2+1=15` linear interpolations.
3. **linear interpolation**

   ```
   X = X0 + (X1-X0)*t
   ```

   - `X` is interpolated point
   - `X0,X1` are the 'left','right' points
   - `t` is the distance parameter `<0,1>`

Comment: I move the previous part to my question section. To get the table from X->Y, if we use tri-linear interpolation, the we need a pool of regular sample data in X space. But in this case, the sample data are not on regular grid points. So for arbitrary data point x in X space, we can find the closest sample data pairs {(xi,yi)}, but the position of xi is not guaranteed to around x. Another difficulty is that the yi might far away, even if xi is close to each other, which due to the nY->1X nature.

Comment: @ohmygoddess you do not need regular grid points!!! when you use generic points then you just need proper points distance (not just in single axis) and the finding of close points is a bit more complicated but the rest is the same as for regular grid points.