# Downsampling of fMRI image with FSL

Tags: image-processing, imaging, medical, neuroscience

I have a set of fMRI images. One group has a dimensionality of 90 x 60 x 12 x 350 with voxel dimension 1 x 1 x 1 mm (350 volumes). The other group has a dimensionality of 80 x 35 x 12 x 350 with voxel dimension 0.2 x 0.2 x 0.5 mm. I'm using one of the images as reference image for registration. Due to the difference in resolution the registration fails (with flirt). So I have to first downsample or upsample. I have tried the following approach:

flirt    -in    input_image \
          -ref good_size_image \
          -out output_image \
          -applyxfm \
           -init /usr/share/fsl/5.0/etc/flirtsch/ident.mat

This does not work, not for downsampling and not for upsampling.

How should I do correct downsampling / upsampling?

Comment: for starters `tri-linear interpolation` see this [inverse interpolation of multidimensional grids](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25658628/2521214) it might help a bit (the image there is tri linear filtering) but I suggest you google out tri-linear interpolation (Wiki)

Comment: when you say 'this does not work' does that mean that your down-/upsampled images do not look right or that the registration of the down/upsampled images fails? maybe some example results would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you have images whose spatial extent are `(a)` 9 x 6 x 1.2 cm^3 and `(b)` 1.6 x 0.7 x 0.6 cm^3? Those are quite small and quite different. I can imagine that if image 2 covers a very specific sub-region of image 1 (because it is much smaller) you may need to give a good starting estimate to get a correct result.

if `input_image` has the dimensions `(b)` and `good_size_image` has the dimensions `(a)` then with the call

```
flirt -in input_image 
      -ref good_size_image 
      -out output_image 
      -applyxfm
```

(`init` option is not strictly necessary in this case),

your output will be the image showing the much smaller space in much larger voxels. I assume the output image would have the size of the reference image (that is the idea of the reference image) but most of it would be empty. Switching `(a)` and `(b)` would not make sense because the space of the reference image can then only cover a tiny part of the input. You would need to register first.

You may want to experiment with the option `applyisoxfm` which resamples an image to cubic voxels of a given size.

```
flirt -in small_image -ref small_image -out small_1mm -applyisoxfm 1
```

will resample the image that covers the space (b) to 1x1x1 mm^3. Again, that is probably to coarse a resolution for so small a space. maybe resample both images to 0.5 mm isotropic and then register?

For these problems the [FSL mailing list](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/lists/FSL.html) is a much better
 place to find help.

Comment: +1 for `-applyisoxfm`, which handles changing the origin correctly (`-applyxfm -init $FSLDIR/etc/flirtsch/ident.mat` + `fslcreatehd` doesn't and creates higher resolution images but with an incorrect origin)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the fslmaths -subsamp2 command?

Comment: I upvoted because this is an oft-used approach, and OP should be aware of it, however, `fslmaths -subsamp2` causes some pretty bad aliasing. `flirt ... -applyisoxfm 2` gives considerably better results.

Comment: `-subsamp2` is definitely easier (and can be used in a sequence of commands of one `fslmaths` call) but does not usually respect the geometry. One place where this matters is downsampling a MNI space image at 2mm (size 91x109x91). Standard 4mm MNI images have size 45x54x45, but `-subsamp2` will give you 46x55x46.